# Script a mobile recharge website

Tags: shell-script, scripting, curl, web

I recently come to know that I can curl a website using the bash command

```
curl --user user:pass xyz.com
```

I have an idea for recharging my mobile using the bash script. I want to write a script which can automaically recharges my mobile using Paytm website. I want this script for my usage only so I will be adding my login credentials, mobile number. As I have already added my account info on Paytm, I just need to enter my CVV. So I just want to enter my CVV when the script runs. I am not much aware about it that how can I do this. Any help will be appreciated. Any other requirement to the question will be added further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Paytm in particular, but generally in Chrome you copy a request as a curl request.

- Enter Your information and open Inspect Element window or Press (F12)
- Go to Network tab
- Press Login/Recharge, whatever the button to proceed
- In the Network tab at the left, you can see a new item added, that's your request
- Press on the request and verify it by checking on the right "Query String Parameters"
- You can see your username/password and any other inputs
- Back to left side, right-click on the same request you can find "Copy as cURL (bash)"
- Now you've the same request as curl command in bash